# Adding Data Values inside a data table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

Hey guys how do you add two values on separate fields but on the same table

for example:

```
tblbooks

Quantity
Borrowed
```

each time a user issue a book to a borrower the Quantity its reduce by 1 and Borrowed is added by 1....

Comment: Are you asking for [**computed columns**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx)?

Comment: sure i think im gonna need that too for summarizing the borrowed books..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2)
VALUES(v1,v2)
```

In your case I guess you need to update.

```
Update yourtable
SET Quantity =Quantity-1,
    Borrowed=Borrowed+1
Where userid=1
```

Comment: `DataTable` is also tagged, so i assume that he wants to know how to do it in-memory.

Comment: wait isn't the "Where bookid= txtbookid.text"
??? or is it really gonna update the data that has a userid 1?

Comment: ive tried this before but it only affects the first row.....when i tried to issue other data it doesn't add or minus up...

Comment: yeah so txtbookid.text = ISBN on the  tbl books....so why is it not updating properly?

Comment: yeah i solved it again...and yet again it has some conflicts with some of the data connections ive made ...Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The way I generally do it is select the row I want to update using LinQ and then just update the values.

For example:

```
    With (From rw In tblBooks Select rw Where rw.Item("MyCondition").ToString = "Condition").First
        .Item("Quantity") = .Item("Quantity") - 1
        .Item("Borrowed") = .Item("Borrowed") + 1
    End With
```

... I didn't test this code, and it doesn't take into account conversion, error checking, etc, but I hope it conveys the idea...